# Transferring database tables to Classes/ Classes to database tables

Tags: c#, database, oop, dapper

This is a more detailed example question that I asked for: [Best Practice with classes and the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965736/best-practice-with-classes-and-the-database)

I'm using c# with Sql Server and using Dapper as my ORM.

Here are my tables:
[image]

Here is my class that will load the Component table into the application:

```
class DBComponent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Component { get; set; }
    public int Material_ID { get; set; }
    public int Color_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then I need my other class that will have the actual values:

```
class Component
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Component { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public Component(DBComponent C)
    {
        ID = C.ID;
        Component = C.Component;
        Material = //queries the Material Table passing in C.Material_ID and returning the Material Value
        Color = //queries the Color Table passing in C.Color_ID and returning the Color Value
    }
}
```

The reason I'm doing this is so that I can use the values for a WinForm application with controls(combobox) and other needs. Also the "DBComponent" Class would have a method that would take a "Component" object and create a "DBComponent" object which would be sent back to the database as a new record.

Is this the best way to handle this situation? Or is there a better method? In my other post someone mentioned that dapper can do this by itself to where I won't need to create 2 classes, only need 1 class. How is that so?

Comment: You can use implicit operators to do this. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit

Comment: @Egbert I can see how using implicit could be used here, I don't think I'll use it in this situation, but I love the concept, I will use implicit in other parts of my project, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use just one class and just one query to load your data. It is just a matter to build the correct sql query and let Dapper do its magic in mapping the data retrieved to your Component class.

Suppose you change your component class like this

```
public class Component
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ComponentX { get; set; }
    public int Color_ID { get; set; }
    public int Material_ID { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public string Color {get;set;}
}
```

now you can retrieve your data using a proper join between the tables

```
IEnumerable<Component> SelectComponents()
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection())
    {
        const string query = @"SELECT p.ID, p.Component as ComponentX, 
                                      p.Color_ID, p.Material_ID, 
                                      c.Color, m.Material 
                                FROM Component p 
                                JOIN Color c on p.Color_ID = c.ID 
                                JOIN Material m on p.Material_ID = m.ID";

        return connection.Query<Component>(query, null);
    }
}
```

Notice that I have renamed the member Component to ComponentX because you can't have a member name with the same name of the enclosing type

Comment: So technically I wouldn't need to have Color_ID and Material_ID in the class with that query right?

Comment: No, you can avoid them if you like, but it doesn't hurt to have them for future uses. Of course you don't display that values to your user, but this is just a problem of your UI interface.

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate your help, This was a lot easier than I thought it was going to be. It all depends on the query. Thanks!